# I cannot obtain numerical values from input elements, even using parseInt

Tags: javascript, input, parseint

I am making a speed calculator where you enter the numbers and you get a speed.
here is the code...

```
<html>
<head><title>speed</title></head>
<body>
<font face="arial">
<h1>Speed Calculator</h1>
<form>
distance: <input type="text" size="3" id="distance">
</form>
time: <input type="text" size="3" id="hours"> Hours
<pre>
<pre>
<input type="button" value="Speed" id="button">
<script>
var dist = parseInt(document.getElementById("distance").value, 10);
var hours = parseInt(document.getElementById("hours").value, 10);
var speed = parseInt(dist, 10) + parseInt(hours, 10);
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function () {
    alert("the speed you were traveling is " + speed + "mph")
}
</script>
</font>
<body>
<html>
```

I enter the numbers but it returns "the speed you were traveling is NaNmph".
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Because that code runs on page-load, not after values have been entered; therefore there is no value in the elements, which means that `parseInt()` can't return a number, hence `NaN`. Incidentally, the `<font>` element has been long-since deprecated and obsoleted; please stop using it (and, possibly, update your reference material from which you're learning).

Comment: You only have to `parseInt` the `distance` and `hours` values once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will retrieve the values of the form fields when the page is loaded and they're still empty.  You need to set those variables inside the `button.onclick` function instead, so they get the values of the fields as of the time the button is pressed.

You only need to `parseInt` the values once.